# Can default alarms be accessed as audio files?

Tags: alarm, android-11, google-pixel-2

For a Pixel 2 with Android 11, are the default alarms stored locally as audio files? If yes, can the files be accessed through a file browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default audio files that come with Android are encoded using the [OGG Vorbis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorbis) encoder and therefore you can find them in file-.system as `.ogg` files.

On Pixel phones the audio files are located in the path `/product/media/audio/alarms/` respectively `/system/product/media/audio/alarms/` (visible in this path in file manager apps like [Cx File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cxinventor.file.explorer)).

Use a file manager app or `adb` to access those files. the path is a bit different.